# How to restrict the number of processes a user can start?

Tags: server, security, resource-limiting

We tried `/etc/security/limits.conf`, but that seems to have no effect.

The used line for limits.conf looks as follows:

```
myuser hard nproc 6
```

That is configuration for a server. I want to limit the processes started. Ulimit limits the processes started from the shell (if I understand that right). But in my case apache starts mapserver-processes, and that number have to be limited.

Comment: What's the exact line you have in limits.conf?  Update the question with it if you could.

Comment: There is a similar question on serverfault: [how to limit the number of simultaneous processes ?](http://serverfault.com/q/184043/51929)

Comment: Logout all instances of myuser before testing,as the limits are set upon login.Also see this http://ss64.com/bash/limits.conf.html

Comment: `/etc/security/limits.conf` is a configuration file for PAM's pam_limits module, but Apache isn't spawning processes through PAM, so it will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the ideal solution because it can interfere with apache upgrades, but it should work.

Edit /etc/init.d/apache2, on the top of the script (new line after the #!/bin/sh) add the required ulimit, example:

```
ulimit -u 1024
```